# Hide Multiple Gridview rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a data bound grid with autogenerated columns set to true becasue its using a sql data source with a stored procedure.  I've found a way to hide one column by

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
 e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
}
```

I want to hide the whole column completely

But how do I hide multiple columns.  Say I have 10 columns and want to hide columns 2, 5 and 7 using :

```
 e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false
 e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = false
 e.Row.Cells[6].Visible = false
```

I'll get a out of range exception.  Is there an alternate way to handle this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you wanting to hide the column all-together, or only for specific rows?

Comment: Can't you hide the columns from back to the beginning?
Like

`e.Row.Cells[6].Visible = false;
e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = false;`

Comment: No doing that throws an out of range exception when trying to hide more than one column at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the next line in a `button_click` event or in the `OnDataBound` event of the `gridview`, which happens when the `GridView` was bind.

```
protected void GridView_OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GridView.Columns[1].Visible = false;
   GridView.Columns[4].Visible = false;
   GridView.Columns[6].Visible = false;
}
```

**EDIT**

For `autogenerated` columns, use this code in your `OnRowDataBound` event of your gridview

```
protected void gridView_OnRowDataBound (object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Pager) { e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">`

and use Temp Field when you need

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ID_Dodavatel") %>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```